# Clojure: War Compilation Failure with Missing Data File Dependency

Tags: clojure, filenotfoundexception, leiningen, slurp

I am working on an webapp that relies on a certain data file to be slurped at runtime.  Without the datafile present I don't seem to be able to compile.  Why is this?

This is in my core.clj

```
(def my-data (slurp "my-file.txt"))
```

Then when I try to compile:

```
$ lein ring war
```

I get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: my-file.txt (No such file or directory), compiling:(core.clj:24:28)
```

How can I compile my war?  I don't need the file to be slurped or even check for existence at compile time.  Thanks in advance!

[UPDATE]

This is not specific to war file packaging or ring, for example:

```
(ns slurp-test.core
    (:gen-class))

(def x (slurp "/tmp/foo.txt"))

(defn -main [& args]
    (println x))
```

Then:

```
 $ lein uberjar
 Compiling slurp-test.core
 (ns slurp-test.core
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/foo.txt (No such file or directory), compiling:(core.clj:4:8)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiling a Clojure source file involves evaluating all top-level forms. This is in fact strictly necessary to support the expected semantics -- most notably, macros couldn't work properly otherwise<sup>1</sup>.

If you AOT compile your code, top-level forms will be evaluated at compile time, and then again at run time as your compiled code is loaded.

For this reason, it is generally not a good idea to cause side effects in code living at top level. If an app requires initialization, it should be performed by a function (typically `-main`).

---

<sup>1</sup> A macro is a function living in a Var marked as a macro (with `:macro true` in the Var's metadata; there's a `setMacro` method on `clojure.lang.Var` which adds this entry). Macros must clearly be available to the compiler, so they must be loaded at compile time. Furthermore, in computing an expansion, a macro function may want to call non-macro functions or otherwise make use of the values of arbitrary Vars resulting from evaluating any top-level code occurring before the point where the macro is invoked. Removing these capabilities would cripple the macro facility rather badly.

Comment: So in a webservice with a framework like compojure, would that happen in the app section?  Which function hooks into the main? `(def app
    (compojure.handler/site main-routes))`

Comment: I'd like to have the app start up with a set of big initial data, and then have that data rebuilt periodically and reloaded.

Comment: It would happen in whichever function your deployment environment will call to start your app. With `lein run`, it'll be `-main` in the main namespace (see `:main` in `project.clj`; you could change this, but there's no reason to). A Java container will want to call a method in a class you supply, so you'll need to implement such a method (that's what `gen-class` is for -- see `(doc gen-class)` and the excellent [gen-class – how it works and how to use it](http://kotka.de/blog/2010/02/gen-class_how_it_works_and_how_to_use_it.html) blog post by Meikel Brandmeyer for more details).

Comment: Replying to the second comment: no problem -- write a function to prepare and load your data, then have your init function call it *and* make arrangements so that it's called at intervals as the app is running. In this case I'd probably put that data in an Atom rather than a Var.

Comment: Hm, thats interesting, I'm trying to think of what would qualify as an init script.  Would that be in say, core.clj, ie where I define routes?

Comment: ie like here:  `(compojure.core/defroutes main-routes
    (compojure.core/GET "/hello" [] "Hello")
    (compojure.route/not-found "Not found"))

(def app
    (compojure.handler/site main-routes))`

Comment: With the hook in project.clj `:ring {:handler myapp.core/app}`

Comment: `lein-ring` takes an `:init` parameter which is just the ticket. See the "General options" section of the [README](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring/blob/0.8.5/README.md) (link to the 0.8.5 release).